# Sovren Resume Parser - Python

Tags: python, api

I am trying to use the Sovren Resume Parser API and I am pretty new to APIs. My application is in Django-Python and thus, I would like to implement call and receive this API using a Python Script.

Documentation - http://resumeparsing.com/

I need a general overview of how to go about this.

Comment: There is no python api?

Comment: Apparently not. There is just the API documentation but I believe we need to build a Python Parsing Client.

Comment: If I get a chance later I will throw a python solution together

Comment: Thanks for your help Padraic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from zeep import Client

client = Client('http://services.resumeparsing.com/ResumeService.asmx?wsdl')

response = client.service.GetAccountInfo(request={'AccountId': 'AccountId','ServiceKey':'ServiceKey'})
print(response)
```

Using the Zeep module did the trick! This works with Python3 as well!

Answer (score 0):

I've used following code in Python to parse job order and resume.

One thing I couldn't figure out is to zip/compress request data. The output from zlib.compress() or gzip.compress() doesn't work. The web service complains about data conversion failure.

```
from zeep import Client
import os

#If required, set proxy.
#os.environ["http_proxy"] = 'http://user:password@host:port'
#os.environ["https_proxy"] = 'https://user:password@host:port'

account_id = 'account_id'
service_key = 'service_key'

client = Client('http://services.resumeparsing.com/ParsingService.asmx?wsdl')

with open('C:/temp/jd.docx', 'rb') as in_file:
    file_bytes = in_file.read()

request = {'AccountId':account_id, 'ServiceKey':service_key, 'FileBytes':file_bytes}

response = client.service.ParseJobOrder(request)
# Similarlly ParseResume() for parsing resume.

print('response.Code = ', response.Code)
print('response.SubCode = ', response.SubCode)
print('response.Message = ', response.Message)
print('response.Xml = ', response.Xml)
```